# Add Key data masking BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, data-masking

i am starting to use data masking on GCP.

Searching the net I did not find anything. I wanted to know if someone had also used a KEY to strengthen crypting

thank you
Hello

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements ?.

Comment: I would like to add a key to have stronger encryptiona key to have stronger encryption

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery supports data masking. You can use [data masking](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-data-masking-intro) to hide sensitivity data. To apply data masking to columns first you have to set up a data catalog taxonomy with policy tags after that you have to create data policies for policy tags and then you have to set policy tags on columns. This way you can hide your sensitive data.

BigQuery automatically [encrypts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/encryption-at-rest) all data before it is written to disk. The data is automatically decrypted when read by an authorized user. By default, Google manages the cryptographic keys on your behalf using the same hardened key management systems that we use for our own encrypted data. Each BigQuery object's data and metadata is encrypted under the Advanced Encryption Standard(AES). If you want to manage the key encryption keys used for your data at rest, instead of having Google manage the keys, use Cloud Key Management Service to manage your keys. This scenario is known as [customer-managed encryption keys](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/customer-managed-encryption#console_2) (CMEK).